# Expressing some queries without employing JOIN or OUTER JOIN

Tags: join, query

Assume the following relations schemas:

- `S(A,B)`
- `T(B,C)`

Rewrite the following expressions without using join or outer join operators explicitly:

1. `S LEFT OUTER JOIN T`
2. `S FULL OUTER JOIN T`

How do I do these two questions? I've tried using a `where` clause but I don't think it is correct. I know the first one has to use a `union` but how do I go about writing the queries?

Answer (score -1):

Left outer join will be:

```
select s.a, s.b, (select c from t where s.b =t.b) as outercol
from s
```

Full outer join will be:

```
select s.a, s.b, (select c from t where s.b =t.b) as outercol
from s
union all
select null, b, c from t
where b not in (select b from s)
```

Comment: Unless `b` is a unique key in `T`, these will not work.

Comment: Null value in `b` is problematic, but why should `b` be be unique. Maybe I am missing something. Please see my test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f186/1

Comment: What does null have to do with uniqueness? See the problem with your queries: [SQL-fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64a3f/1)

Comment: What I meant is my union query does not include rows like `T(null, 4)`. But it does work with rows `T(5, 4), T(5, 8)`, which are non-unique `b` values in `T`.

Comment: Your query does not work. Check the fiddle in the above comment.

Comment: I got it. `a` should be a unique key in S. But I was not getting why `b` needs to be a unique key in T.